# Creating list of lists containing objects in python

Tags: python, list, object

I am trying to put a custom object into a 2d list and I'm getting very confused. 
Here's what I have:

Here's the cell class:

```
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, what, cost):
        self.what = what
        self.parentx = -1
        self.parenty = -1
        self.f = 0
        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.cost = cost
```

and my insertion object (where I take a grid/ maze and put the data into objects):

```
def insertion (r, c, grid):
    cellGrid = []
    for x in range(0, r):
        for y in range(0, c):
            if (grid[x][y] == '%'):
                what = 0
                cost = 100000000
            elif(grid[x][y] == '-'):
                what = 1
                cost = 1
            elif (grid[x][y] == '.'):
                what = 2
                cost = 0
            else:
                what = 3
            cellGrid.append(Cell(what, cost))
    return cellGrid
```

This does work, but what I really want is cellGrid to be a 2d list, just like grid, except that it will contain cell objects intstead of a string.  I would like to be able to acceess it as `cellGrid[0][0].what` for example.  How should I accomplish this?

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: Don  mix tabs and spaces  - in particular, never do that in Python code. You might use tabs, but it is preferable to use just spaces - MUCH preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that you need to create a 'row'  in the first loop to add into the main `grid` array. You then append cells to this row, and append the whole row to the grid.

Like so:

```
def insertion (r, c, grid):
    cellGrid = []
    for x in range(0, r):
        row = []
        for y in range(0, c):
            if (grid[x][y] == '%'):
                what = 0
                cost = 100000000
            elif(grid[x][y] == '-'):
                what = 1
                cost = 1
            elif (grid[x][y] == '.'):
                what = 2
                cost = 0
            else:
                what = 3
            row.append(Cell(what, cost))
        cellGrid.append(row)
    return cellGrid
```

Comment: Nice and simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions to create a list of lists full of `None`s. Change cellGrid initialization to:

```
cellGrid = [ [None for i in range(c)] for j in range(r)]
```

then you do

```
cellGrid[x][y] = Cell(what,cost)
```

Full code example:

```
def insertion (r, c, grid):
    cellGrid = [ [None for i in range(c)] for j in range(r)]
    for x in range(0, r):
        for y in range(0, c):
            if (grid[x][y] == '%'):
                what = 0
                cost = 100000000
            elif(grid[x][y] == '-'):
                what = 1
                cost = 1
            elif (grid[x][y] == '.'):
                what = 2
                cost = 0
            else:
                what = 3
            cellGrid[x][y] = Cell(what,cost)
    return cellGrid
```